# Php I can't delete a row of a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can't delete a row that I choose with the input delete. I think that I have to set other parameters in the querydelete but i dont know exactly what.

Can anyone help me because Im a beginner? Is there another way to do something like that?

My purpose is to push the delete input and then delete the customer with the specific id (in the same raw with the delete input).

Can anyone give me a link with an example?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Table with database</title>
<style>
 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
  color: #588c7e;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
   } 
th {
  background-color: #588c7e;
  color: white;
   }
 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th> 
  <th>Room</th> 
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Check In</th> 
  <th>Check Out</th> 
   </tr>

 <?php

  include('db_connection.php');
  $conn = OpenCon();

    //SQL query 
     $query = "Select * from ergazomenos"; 

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $querydelete = "delete from ergazomenos where trim(ID) 
    ='$_POST[hidden]'";
   $queryexee = mysqli_query($conn, $querydelete);

    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 

    if (!$result){
       echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }


    //query database 

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

         $ID = $rows['ID'] ;
            $Room = $rows['Room'] ;
         $Name = $rows['Name'];
         $CheckIn = $rows['Check In'] ;
         $CheckOut = $rows['Check Out'] ;




        //echo "</td><td>" . $ID. "</td><td>" "<input type=hidden ID=hidden 
value=" . $rows['ID'] . $Room. "</td><td>". $Name. "</td><td>" . $CheckIn. " 
</td><td>" . $CheckOut. "</td><td>";


            echo "</td><td>" . $ID. "</td><td>" . $Room. "</td><td>". $Name. 
  "</td><td>" . $CheckIn. "</td><td>" . $CheckOut. "</td><td>"; 
            </td>";


        echo ("<form action=delete.php method=post>");
        echo ("<tr><td><div align=\"center\"> $ID </div>" . "<input 
        type=hidden name=hidden value=".$rows['ID'] . "</td> <td><div 
        align=\"center\"> 
      $Room </div></td> <td><div align=\"center\"> $Name </div></td> <td><div 
  align=\"center\"> $CheckIn </div></td> <td><div align=\"center\"> $CheckOut 
  </div></td> <td><div align=\"center\">  <td><div   ");    
        echo ("<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete"  . " 
  </td>");      
        //    
          echo ($rows['ID']);
                //echo '<td><input type="button" name="delete" 
  value="delete"></td>';
                echo ("</tr>");
       echo ($_POST['hidden']);
      }  


  CloseCon($conn);



   ?> 

    </table>


  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Insert</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Update</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide an example of a row of the data in the DB. This will help people figure out whether ID is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You should using prepare statement to prevent SQL injection

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$id = $_POST['hidden'];

// if you are using ID, make sure variable is number
if (is_numeric(id)) {

delete from ergazomenos where trim(ID) 
    ='$_POST[hidden]'

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "DELETE FROM ergazomenos WHERE trim(ID) = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

it's more secure this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing the **$querydelete** from:

```
$querydelete = "delete from ergazomenos where trim(ID) 
='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

to

```
$querydelete = "delete from ergazomenos where trim(ID)=". $_POST['hidden'];
```

This should help. I didn't test the code, tho.

Comment: i would also add some input sanitizing, eg. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use (single or escaped double) quotes for the attribute values in your `input` tag/s:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden' [etc.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my style.

Create a column in grid named `Action` and along each db driven record.

```
<td>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>">Delete</a>
</td>
```

In `delete.php` file:

```
include('connection.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query= "delete from table where id = '$id'";
mysqli_query($conn, $query); // or $dbConn->query($query);
```

Redirect to grid page.

Comment: That is bad style. You should not submit actions which change the state with `GET`, because browsers are allowed to pre-fetch links, thus causing automatic deletion of all records listed.

Comment: Yup agreed. 
Could be in post or api style. I shared w.r.t the question author and an easy way than his style.